# Change H1 Style On Click (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I butchered this :/ I'm trying to make it where my header tags will change `onclick`. Is addClass/removeClass more efficient/debatably better?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/3ojmnpgk/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h1>This is my Header!</h1>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {

    //Change Style: If Default to Red
    if ($("h1").css({"color":"default"});){

        $("h1").css({"color":"red"});
        });
    } else {}

    //Change Style: If Red to Blue
    if ($("h1").css({"color":"red"});){

        $("h1").css({"color":"blue"});
        });
    } else {}     

    //Change Style: If Blue to Default
    if ($("h1").css({"color":"blue"});){

        $("h1").css({"color":"default"});
        });
    } else {}

    //May add more colors
});
```

Comment: `default` is not a valid value for the `color` directive

Comment: *Is addClass/removeClass more efficient/debatably better* : In your case, Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things in your code preventing it to work.

```
if(...) else {}
if(...) else {}
if(...) else {}
```

First of all you don't need an else if it is empty. Second if you write it like this your conditions get checked one after another which means your color would change three times until it has the color it had before.
Better write `if(...){} else if(...){} else if(...){}`

```
if(...;)
```

Don't use ";" in a condition.

```
if(...) {... }); }
```

What is "});" doing there?

And finally you can only check a css property with

```
$("h1").css("color") == ...
```

But since it expects a rgb value I wouldn't recommend this approach and instead use classes.

Your code would look like

`$(".arrow").click(function() {
    if($("h1").hasClass("red")) {
       $("h1").removeClass("red");
       $("h1").addClass("green");

    }
    else if($("h1").hasClass("green")) {
       $("h1").removeClass("green");
       $("h1").addClass("blue");

    }
    else if($("h1").hasClass("blue")) {
       $("h1").removeClass("blue");
       $("h1").addClass("red");

    }
});`

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ojmnpgk/8/) for a working example.

Comment: Very easy to read, and I really appreciate all the added instruction!! :)

Comment: I just realized that you added the `class="red"` to my H1. What would I do differently for a H1 tag that doesn't initially have a class?

Comment: You can check with `if(!$("h1").attr("class"))` and go from there. I want to point out however that with `$("h1")` you always select every h1-element of your page. So you will run into problems if you have more than one. Better give the tag an id and select it with `$("#[idname]")`

Comment: Thanks again! And I'm okay with it selecting all H1 tags :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you get the `css` property of an element in jquery, and it does not return the name of the color but its value in `rgb`.

It should be something like this:

```
if( $('h1').css('color')==='rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
    $("h1").css({"color":"blue"});
}
```

I think it's the only part that's preventing your code from working as you expect. Plus the `default` color which should probably just be an empty string `{"color":""}`

Answer (score 1):

On possibility refering to `addClass`/ `removeClass` would :

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {


    var $h1 = $('h1');
    if($h1.hasClass('red')){
        $h1.removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    }else if($h1.hasClass('blue')){
        $h1.removeClass('blue');
    }else{
        $h1.addClass('red');
    }

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfvva1dk/)**

The example for your approach would look like this:

```
$(".arrow").click(function () {

    var $h1 = $("h1");
    var color = $("h1").css("color");
    switch(color){
        case 'rgb(255, 0, 0)':
             $h1.css({"color":"blue"});
            break;
         case 'rgb(0, 0, 255)':
             $h1.css({"color":"black"});
            break;
        default:
            $h1.css({"color":"red"});
            break;
    }

});
```

I would recommend to cache your element, as you use the same elemtn multiple times here.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wctrj9wg/)**

Comment: If he uses [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) he does not need to rely on the element having only one class. One possible source for errors less.

Comment: @ImreNagy you're right, thought too complicated, changed my example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rgb()` for providing color, and use `css()` method with callback function

```js
$(".arrow").click(function() {
  $("h1").css("color", function(i, v) {
    if (v == "rgb(0, 0, 0)")
      return "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    if (v == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
      return "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
    if (v == "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
      return "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  });
});
```

```css
.center {
  margin: 1% 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.arrow {
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h1>This is my Header!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative:

```
$('h1').click(function () {
  $('h1').addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To assist the person who asked the question, please provide a little bit of explanation about why your answer addresses the problem.